# Workbox CacheFirst causing Out of Memory when caching large file

Tags: workbox

I am using workbox-sw CacheFirst Strategy to cache video file. My website will loads a single video tag but will switch between 5 different video with 10 seconds interval. The website will crash and encounter "Out of Memory" error after 20-30mins of playback.

I am using Google Chrome v116 to loads the website below is snippet of the workbox code:

```
new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'video-cache',
      plugins: [
          new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin({
              statuses: [0, 200]
          }),
      ],
})
```

My research
One of my video is around 400MB in file size where I tried removed that specific video from playback. The playback loads fine for few hours.

In addition, I tried to disable workbox cache large file with threshold using cacheWillUdpate plugin. The large video would not attempt to cache but the issue still persist.

```
cacheWillUpdate: async ({ response }) => {
    // threshold 200MB
    if (response.headers.get('Content-Length') > 200000000) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any advice or workaround to resolve the memory leak issue is much appreciated.